# Guassian blur with OpenGL (Not a texture)

Tags: java, user-interface, opengl

I'm trying to render a simple square in OpenGL which has opacity and is blurred, for a game GUI. It should have a guassian blur effect on it (which will blur the game).

I'm using a tesselator to draw the 4 quads of the square if that helps.

Comment: You want a realtime blur of your scene? That is to say, you aren't pausing the game in the background while displaying this effect?

Comment: @WaylonFlinn Yes correct, I want it in real time. Any resources will help, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the general approach to this problem is a post-processing one. First render your scene (to a buffer/texture) then apply an approximate Gaussian blur to the result using a shader. This approximation uses a two step process which separates the blur into a horizontal and vertical component. While this separation is not mathematically precise the results are generally good.

Resources for this are:

1. [Efficient Gaussian Blur with Linear Sampling](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/09/efficient-gaussian-blur-with-linear-sampling/)
2. [Real-Time Glow](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch21.html)
3. [Incremental Computation of the Gaussian Blur](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch40.html)
4. [Practical Post-Process Depth of Field](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch28.html)

Comment: @B3NW Did this turn out to answer your question?

Comment: Another article: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131511/four_tricks_for_fast_blurring_in_.php